# Concatenate values from script-created list into one field

Tags: php, javascript

How do I concatenate data from text fields in a script-created list, where the text field names will always be the same as each other? Allow me to explain:

I have a series of points that get added to a list that is create using javascript. This is the script to create the list:

```
var src = this.parentNode;
var field = $('<input type="text" id="savedpoints" name="savedpoints">').attr({'value': $(src).data('dbId')});
var but = $('<button>').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove&nbsp;&nbsp;');
var newItem = $('<li>').append(field).append($(src).data('marker').title);
newItem.append('&nbsp;').append(but);
$(but).click(poi.removeItem);
$(poi.saveList).append(newItem);
```

So, there are items getting added to a list with a button next to them to remove them from the list if they are no longer needed. This list works perfectly.

What I need is to add the values to a text field at the bottom of the form (say, name="allpoints") that concatenates the field values from this list (the text field labelled "savedpoints", with the attribute 'dbId') into a string (e.g. "6, 7, 10, 13, 14,..." etc) whenever an item is removed from or added to the list. I can't work out how this might work!

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would add an event handler to a common-ancestor of the remove button(s) and add button(s), which completely rebuilds the contents of "allpoints" when triggered:

```
$(commonParent).on('click', 'button.remove, button.add', function () {
    $('[name="allpoints"]').val($('[name="savedpoints"]').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).join(", "));
});
```

... if you wanted to, you could only add/remove the relevant element to/from the list, but you get the gist.

Note you'll need to add a class to your remove `<button>` (I've called it `remove`) in my example, and to your "Add" button.

Comment: Thanks @Matt I think this will probably get close to what I want - however, it doesn't seem to be populating (perhaps because, with each iteration or added item, each item is using the same field name). Can you think of any other way around this? Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: @user1259798: Can you come up with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar which demonstrates your issue? I can't think OTOMH why this won't work.